# What is it the meaning of "amorphous blob"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "amorphous blob" in the following context?

> "Along this ladder, also known as the “Great Chain of Being,” all
>   living things essntially strove to achieve perfection with humans
>   -specifically men- as the most perfect non divine beings at the top and some kind of **amorphous blob** at the bottom" (The Complete Idiot's Guide to College Biology)

I tried to search on google but I didn't find an explanation while I think it's  an idiom.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say "amorphous blob" is an idiom, but you often hear those words together. Amorphous blob simply means an undefined amount or pile of matter that is amorphous. Amorphous means not having an organized (molecular) structure, which results in a visible unorganized shape.

> amorphous: without a clearly defined shape or form.

So, in your sample paragraph, amorphous blob simply means some kind of large being without a defined shape.

To give you some more help, here's what I found when I searched amorphous blob on Google images:

[image: amorphous blob]

Comment: +1 for the purple image and for keeping a straight face in your answer. I consider "amorphous blob" to be idiomatic in common American English usage, but I still love your answer. Thank you.